# New Base for outdoor dusk to dawn lights

Tags: electrical

I have 2 outdoor dusk to dawn lights and I would like to change the base of light so that I can attach an outdoor cam and still have my  dusk to dawn light. Is there something out there like that. I see outdoor lights with a base that you can plug something in, but not a base I can buy separately.Im trying to cut costs and I had those lights installed about a year ago.

Comment: show us a picture of current base